# Node.js: Background jobs not restarting unless server is restarted

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to node.js, pardon me in case this is something trivial.

I am trying to integrated `Bull` for background processing in the application and have noticed that when a error happens during processing, jobs do not retry until the server is restarted. even in case of a error job still remain in the `active` state and are not moved to `failed`

Below is the relevant part of my code

```
queue.js
const Queue = require('bull');
const { setQueues } = require('bull-board');
const csvExportsQueue = new Queue('csv exports');
setQueues([csvExportsQueue]);
module.exports = csvExportsQueue;
```

I am listening to failed and error events but none of them seem to be triggering when a exception happens

```
worker.js
const csvExportProcessing = require('./queue');
const processExport = require('./process_export');

csvExportProcessing.process(function(job, done){
  processExport.performExport(job.data.params, done).catch(err => {
    console.log('in error handling'); // I see this outputted on the console
  });
});


csvExportProcessing.on('completed', function(job, result){
  console.log('job is now completed');
});


csvExportProcessing.on('failed', function(job, err){
  console.log('failed');
});


csvExportProcessing.on('error', function(job, err){
  console.log('error');
});
```

So, a post request is received on endpoint `/exports`, which adds a job to the queue, below is the code

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const exportCsv = require('./process_export');
const exportQueue = require('./queue');

router.post('/', (req, resp, next) => {
  console.log('received request...adding to the queue');
  exportQueue.add({params: req.body}, {attempts:5, backoff: 5000 });
  next();
});

module.exports = router;
```

And i start the server using `npm start` which shows the below output

```
> nodemon server.js

[nodemon] 2.0.3
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
```

Any help in how i can fix this would be really great. Thanks.

Comment: How are _queue.js_ and _worker.js_ implemented with regards to your server code?

Comment: hi @1252748, i have updated my question with more details

Comment: What types of errors are you getting? And how do you want to handle them?

Comment: hi @1252748, i have introduced a error but mistyping a variable name and i see this exception in code `ReferenceError: myCsvData is not defined` and i expected that job would restart but it does not untill i restart the server and job remains in active state

Comment: Yeah it's not going to recover from your javascript error; I am not familiar with Bull, but I'm guessing it has some internal mechanism to handle its own errors and pass them to some listenable event, but it won't catch your syntax errors